# Prove compact set and index set

Tags: general-topology, compactness

\begin{equation}
\forall α \in I\; A_α \text{ is a compact set} \implies \bigcap \{ A_\alpha : \alpha \in I\} \text{ is a compact set}
\end{equation}

How to prove this problem?

I know definition of compact, but I can't use it.

Comment: Did you try open covers?

Comment: I try open covers, but this book has no solution.

Comment: If compact includes Hausdorff, it is trivial...